# firebase upload & get photo with ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm trying to upload an get photo in my Ionic 2 app. I succeeded to run the camera and save the photo in Firebase but not to get and display it on my app. I'm not sure i'm doing it right, the save in Firebase.

I put here my code.

add-note.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';


import {NotesData} from "../../providers/notes-data";

/*
  Generated class for the AddNote page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-note',
  templateUrl: 'add-note.html'
})
export class AddNote {
  public notePicture: any;



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public notesData:NotesData) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }
  addNote() {
    this.notesData.addPhoto(this.notePicture);

    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

  takePicture(){
    Camera.getPicture({
      quality : 95,
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit : true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
      targetWidth: 500,
      targetHeight: 500,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    }).then(imageData => {
      this.notePicture = imageData;
    }, error => {
      console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }


}
```

note-data.ts //provider for notes to upload the photo to firebase

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import firebase from 'firebase'
/*
 Generated class for the NotesData provider.

 See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
 for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
 */
@Injectable()
export class NotesData {
  //user data
  public currentUser: any;
  public profilePictureRef: any;
  //notedata
  public notesList: any;

  //firebase data
  public photoRef:any;


  constructor() {
    this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.fireRef=firebase.database().ref();
    this.photoRef=firebase.database().ref('users/'+this.currentUser+'/photos');
    this.notesList = 
  }

  addPhoto(notePicture:any){
    this.photoRef.push({id:"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+notePicture});

  }


}
```

my firebase structure photo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Firebase Storage and store URLs in your Firebase. You're going to cost yourself a lot of extra money and headaches by storing your image data in the realtime database.

The new SDKs have great APIs for uploading images that can be publicly accessed.

Comment: What is the new sdks? Can you share more details how can i do that?

Comment: I'm referring to Firebase 3 which was launched in May - maybe you did start using Firebase after that. Anyway, the new SDKs have easy methods for you to store binary / raw data in Google Cloud Storage. You should be using that to store images instead of base64 images stored in the realtime database. Store the image in Google Cloud Storage and then store the public URL to that image in Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the whole url, just save short path. As you can find at [my blog post about uploading, and getting data from firebase storage](http://muhammetbakan.com/angular2-ionic2-how-to-upload-and-get-image-from-firebase-storage/), it's just 2 lines of code to get actual url with permissions.

```
                this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
                this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url =>
                    console.log(url)
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [angular-firebase npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-firebase) it is simple and easy to use

```
npm install angular-firebase
```

and you can simply upload the captured base 64 image
with this code

```
this.firebase.uploadString(encodedFile,'images/1.jpg','base64',
(v)=>{
    console.log('Upload progress :'v + '% uploaded');   
    // event detect the data uploaded  used to monitor the persentage of the download process
    // this will return 'Upload progress : 24% uploaded'
// for example 
}).then((url)=>{
    console.log(url);
    //the URL of uploaded file or image
});
```